# Java DOM Parser returns null pointer on some strings but not others

Tags: java, xml, dom, jodatime

I don't know what could be causing it. In the function I attached below, I have three strings that are read from the XML file correctly, and three marked "Problem", all of which cause a Null Pointer Exception. They are done in exactly the same way as the first three. Some things I've tried include changing the call to:

```
act.RemainingLateFinishDate  = new DateTime(initElement.getElementsByTagName("RemainingLateFinishDate").item(0).getNodeValue());
```

This doesn't cause a Null Pointer Exception anymore, but instead seems to return an empty string, which is equally as useless. Another thing I tried was taking all the DOM stuff out of the JODA DateTime constructor, which, as you might know, didn't make the slightest difference.

Here is the function:

```
private Activity getActivity(Element initElement){//collect activity data from xml
    Activity act = new Activity();
    act.setName(initElement.getElementsByTagName("Name").item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue());
    act.OriginalDuration = Integer.parseInt(initElement.getElementsByTagName("PlannedDuration").item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue());
    act.RemainingDuration = Integer.parseInt(initElement.getElementsByTagName("RemainingDuration").item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue());
    act.ActualDuration = Integer.parseInt(initElement.getElementsByTagName("ActualDuration").item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue());

    act.EACDuration = act.RemainingDuration + act.ActualDuration;
    if(act.EACDuration>act.OriginalDuration)act.ActivitySlippage = true;
    else act.ActivitySlippage = false;
    if(act.EACDuration<=act.OriginalDuration)act.ActivityPerformedWell = true;
    else act.ActivityPerformedWell = false;

    //Problem============================================================
    act.RemainingLateFinishDate  = new DateTime(initElement.getElementsByTagName("RemainingLateFinishDate").item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue());
    act.RemainingEarlyFinishDate = new DateTime(initElement.getElementsByTagName("RemainingEarlyFinishDate").item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue());
    act.PlannedFinishDate = new DateTime(initElement.getElementsByTagName("PlannedFinishDate").item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue());
    //===================================================================

    act.Float1 = new Duration(act.RemainingEarlyFinishDate,act.RemainingLateFinishDate);
    act.Float2 = new Duration(act.PlannedFinishDate,act.RemainingLateFinishDate);
    if(act.Float1.isLongerThan(act.Float2))act.TotalFloat = act.Float2;
    else act.TotalFloat = act.Float1;

    if(act.TotalFloat.isShorterThan(Duration.ZERO)||act.TotalFloat.isEqual(Duration.ZERO))act.CriticalActivity = true;
    if(act.TotalFloat.isShorterThan(Duration.ZERO))act.NegativeFloatActivity = true;

    return act;
}
```

I can't include the XML file because it's *really* long. If you would like me to post it somewhere, please express that concern. However, you could suffice to say that all the elements I'm referencing are there under the correct node where they should be.

Thanks!

Edit (some XML)

```
<Activity>
                <ActualDuration>0</ActualDuration>
                <ActualFinishDate xsi:nil="true" />
                <ActualLaborCost>0</ActualLaborCost>
                <ActualLaborUnits>0</ActualLaborUnits>
                <ActualNonLaborCost>0</ActualNonLaborCost>
                <ActualNonLaborUnits>0</ActualNonLaborUnits>
                <ActualStartDate xsi:nil="true" />
                <ActualThisPeriodLaborCost>0</ActualThisPeriodLaborCost>
                <ActualThisPeriodLaborUnits>0</ActualThisPeriodLaborUnits>
                <ActualThisPeriodNonLaborCost>0</ActualThisPeriodNonLaborCost>
                <ActualThisPeriodNonLaborUnits>0</ActualThisPeriodNonLaborUnits>
                <AtCompletionDuration>1104</AtCompletionDuration>
                <AtCompletionLaborCost>470304</AtCompletionLaborCost>
                <AtCompletionLaborUnits>1104</AtCompletionLaborUnits>
                <AtCompletionNonLaborCost>93840</AtCompletionNonLaborCost>
                <AtCompletionNonLaborUnits>1104</AtCompletionNonLaborUnits>
                <AutoComputeActuals>1</AutoComputeActuals>
                <CalendarObjectId>597</CalendarObjectId>
                <DurationPercentComplete>0</DurationPercentComplete>
                <DurationType>1</DurationType>
                <EstimatedWeight>1</EstimatedWeight>
                <ExpectedFinishDate xsi:nil="true" />
                <ExternalEarlyStartDate xsi:nil="true" />
                <ExternalLateFinishDate xsi:nil="true" />
                <Feedback xsi:nil="true" />
                <FinishDate>2008-05-22T17:00:00</FinishDate>
                <GUID>{841EDB12-3616-0043-BE5D-58C14151D45D}</GUID>
                <Id>LH750</Id>
                <IsNewFeedback>0</IsNewFeedback>
                <LevelingPriority>2</LevelingPriority>
                <Name>Elevator</Name>
                <NonLaborUnitsPercentComplete>0</NonLaborUnitsPercentComplete>
                <NotesToResources xsi:nil="true" />
                <ObjectId>43877</ObjectId>
                <PercentComplete>0</PercentComplete>
                <PercentCompleteType>1</PercentCompleteType>
                <PlannedDuration>1104</PlannedDuration>
                <PlannedFinishDate>2008-05-22T17:00:00</PlannedFinishDate>
                <PlannedLaborCost>470304</PlannedLaborCost>
                <PlannedLaborUnits>1104</PlannedLaborUnits>
                <PlannedNonLaborCost>93840</PlannedNonLaborCost>
                <PlannedNonLaborUnits>1104</PlannedNonLaborUnits>
                <PlannedStartDate>2007-11-13T08:00:00</PlannedStartDate>
                <PrimaryConstraintDate xsi:nil="true" />
                <PrimaryConstraintType xsi:nil="true" />
                <PrimaryResourceObjectId>1716</PrimaryResourceObjectId>
                <ProjectObjectId>462</ProjectObjectId>
                <RemainingDuration>1104</RemainingDuration>
                <RemainingEarlyFinishDate>2008-05-22T17:00:00</RemainingEarlyFinishDate>
                <RemainingEarlyStartDate>2007-11-13T08:00:00</RemainingEarlyStartDate>
                <RemainingLaborCost>470304</RemainingLaborCost>
                <RemainingLaborUnits>1104</RemainingLaborUnits>
                <RemainingLateFinishDate>2008-06-19T17:00:00</RemainingLateFinishDate>
                <RemainingLateStartDate>2008-02-29T08:00:00</RemainingLateStartDate>
                <RemainingNonLaborCost>93840</RemainingNonLaborCost>
                <RemainingNonLaborUnits>1104</RemainingNonLaborUnits>
                <ResumeDate xsi:nil="true" />
                <SecondaryConstraintDate xsi:nil="true" />
                <SecondaryConstraintType xsi:nil="true" />
                <StartDate>2007-11-13T08:00:00</StartDate>
                <Status>0</Status>
                <SuspendDate xsi:nil="true" />
                <Type>2</Type>
                <UnitsPercentComplete>0</UnitsPercentComplete>
                <WBSObjectId>4364</WBSObjectId>


                <....... />

            </Activity>
```

Comment: To help you debug, try to separate out your chained method calls into one statement per line and then see which line the stack trace is initiated from. You can also step through in a debugger easier when it is one line per statement. Can you post the stack trace? Also, just a fragment of the XML would help.

Comment: Any chance that some of your XML is namespaced? In this case you'd need to use getElementsByTagNameNS.

Comment: When I cut it up into five separate statements, the one that causes the Null Pointer Exception is the `getNodeValue()` method call.

Comment: I will try to post some of the XML...

Comment: I am not familiar with that method, I will look it up...

Comment: No, there are no namespaces AFAIK. Furthermore, the other queries worked, and they are also in the `Activity` node with no namespace specified.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which DOM library you're using but what happens if you modify the code like so:

```
act.RemainingLateFinishDate  = new DateTime(initElement.getElementsByTagName("RemainingLateFinishDate").getNodeValue());
```

Comment: That doesn't work because `getElementsByTagName()` returns a NodeList, and `getNodeValue()` is a member of Node, not NodeList.

Comment: My apologies. I should have guessed by the naming. So have you tried stepping through in the debugger to see what is null? From what you said earlier it sounds like the result of item(0) is null.